# Can multiple meteor application server instances work behind Hipache reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, websocket, meteor, reverse-proxy, dotcloud

I want to load balance my Meteor application using Hipache reverse proxy. Single application server instance works well, but when I add the second one, I get the following error in browser:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.local:8000/sockjs/709/gs_aliii/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

Here is the shell script for starting app docker containers and configuring hipache: http://pastebin.com/R1kuW80E

The full setup is here: https://github.com/vlebedev/docker-test

I found the following in hipache issues on github, maybe that is the problem: https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache/issues/3

On the other hand, dotcloud (the creators of hipache) boasts that they support Meteor load balancing. And they use hipache as their incoming request router. That's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the root cause of the problem by myself, here it is: https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache/issues/24

Something is broken with websocket support in hipache with node.js >= 0.10.0. I downgraded node.js in hipache and meteor containers to 0.8.25 and everything is working well now!

Comment: Notably, Meteor doesn't have an official support for node 0.10 either